# Ordered substitution with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, match

I need to replace a set of pattern matched strings to another one.
For example, given a list [10, 20, 30, 40, 50] and a string "a b c d e", I need to replace five letters to each element in the list keeping the order: "10 20 30 40 50". The real case is much more complicated, so I need to use regular expression to find patterns.

I could implement the code as follows, but the issues is that the duplicated letter 'a' is replaced with the same value 10 when the 2nd 'a' should be replaced with '30'.

```
l = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
inp = "a 1    b 2  a 3    d  4 e"

pattern = re.compile("([^\d]+)+(\s+)?")
items = pattern.findall(inp)
print items
for i, item in enumerate(items):

    value = str(l[i])
    inp = re.sub(item[0].strip(), value, inp)
    print inp

#  10 1    20 2  10 3    40  4 50 <-- Wrong result. The 10 is replaced with first and third match.
# It should have been 10 1    20 2  30 3    40  4 50
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What is the "right" result?

Comment: can you give us example using bigger data?

Comment: You might simplify the question too much to understand. If the inp = "a b a d e a", what should the last "a" be replaced?

Comment: Yeah, the question is confusing as OP appears to just want to keep the order the same... lol.  The actual use case might make sense but the example WAY overcomplicates the process of "replacing" an indexed item of one list with the same indexed item of a different list.

Comment: @ddenhartog i think the right result is: 10 20 30 40 50 :)

Comment: @moha: Yeah, which is why I think OP's code is overcomplicated as use of `.sub` appears to be unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `re.sub` with a callback function that takes the next replacement from the list:

```
l = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
inp = "a b a d e"

import re

repl = iter(l)
result = re.sub(r'\w+', lambda m: str(next(repl)), inp)
```

Comment: @MohamedAbdElRaouf: yeah, looks like I misread the question. Edited.

Comment: Why use `.sub` at all?

Comment: @ddenhartog: as stated in the question, the actual problem is more complicated than just `a b c d`.

Comment: So?  The *pattern* is just more complicated. `items` is still just a list

Comment: @ddenhartog: yes, but I presume that parts of the string that don't match should be preserved. Try the above with `inp = "a@b@a@d@e"`

Comment: @thg: Gotcha, thanks.  OP's edit does appear to indicate this! Though his new `inp` doesn't work with your answer

Comment: @thg435: The pattern is not always the same, so I can't use '\w+'. However, I know that a given ['a','b','a','d','e'] in a string should be replaced with [10,20,30,40,50] in order.

Answer (score 0):

The re.sub has an optional count to limit the maximum match. With the setup of count as 1, everything seems to be working fine.

```
import re
l = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
inp = "a 1    b 2  a 3    d  4 e"

pattern = re.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)")
items = pattern.findall(inp)
print items
for i, item in enumerate(items):
    value = str(l[i])
    inp = re.sub(item[0], value, inp, 1)

print inp

# 10 1    20 2  30 3    40  4 50
```

Or

```
repl = iter(l)
# You can use function or lambda
# def rep_obj(matchobj): print matchobj.group(0); return str(next(repl))  
result = re.sub("([a-zA-Z]+)", lambda m: str(next(repl)), inp)
print result

# 10 1    20 2  30 3    40  4 50
```

Comment: I fail to see why you insist on doing the same thing twice (findall+sub).